# Ngnx 1.2.3 truncated Facebook code parameter value because of "#"

Tags: facebook, nginx

i use Facebook authentication with my website.

I use Nginx 1.2.3.

Facebook produce URL with the following pattern :

> =">https://www.mysite.net/profile.xhtml?state=dfecc191-5eb5-4e08-a514-bc70fdc17611&code=AQBKJ_1VuycE7-DPigKfrAt9BLGQJww-p0RKY_Lta6uDxsaMUgzR98soPiOD6NDZ6kyU-NJUHmpAqEOSCxOKi7UGgh0fJSfC9kyh18FtSbQNJdyNEkkfaNtP9GMC8y25W6fOjyR2fj3OnQQTFDwmm-gckqofvhJsmnPSWgHxaan7uiaz_Wgc5JcdTu2DfzhOjqUQ_QG7X14jWDdq9CUtHuSV#*=*

As you can see facebook add `#_=_` at the end of code parameter value.

Now, if you try to build any kind of URL GET with a # in it, NGINX will stop to parse the request when it encountered #, [this for instance](http://www.mysite.net/index.html?value1=jo#hn&value2=doe).

Gives the following log :

> [16/Aug/2012:11:25:33 +0200] "GET /index.html?value1=jo HTTP/1.1" 200 4976 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1"

In my case, Nginx stops to parse the request and remove "#*=*" from code parameter value !

Any idea ?

Thanks.

PS: this works perfectly well with Apache.

Comment: The fragment part of the URL is irrelevant for the actual request, it is just useful for jumping to anchors on the page. So I don't see, how this is an error or apache could make it different?

Answer (score 1):

So the way that server's handle hashes (the #_=_) is that they generally ignore it.

This hash should have no bearing on whether or not the code returned by facebook should work.

What **will** affect it's success is casing. Make sure you're not calling .ToLower() (or similar) on the request parameters before you try and use the code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaking - no browser (expect IE if you confuse it) will ever send the fragment portion of the URL to the server - that is agains the HTTP specification.

That you say this works with Apache is close to impossible.

Your example is a perfectly valid URL, but the URI part is http://www.mysite.net/index.html?value1=jo since #hn&value2=doe is in fact the fragment part of the URL.